# How do I get my header to be full width? Whenever I add another menu item, they become hidden.

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get my header to be full width? Whenever I add another menu item, they become hidden. I know it's because of "Overflow hidden" but when I remove it, it no longer lines up with the logo on Nav bar.

```
    header {
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="BIpY241hd4nsx4Cs9aSUy2kMwYTtmWaaXF2wcVcrmcM" />
width: 200%;
height: 130px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
-moz-transition: height 0.3s;
-ms-transition: height 0.3s;
-o-transition: height 0.3s;
transition: height 0.3s; 
          }
header.header-bg{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
header h1{
padding-top:25px;
}
header h1#logo {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
line-height: 120px;
float: left;
font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
font-size: 60px;
color: white;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s; 
}
header h1#logo .logo-2{
display:none;
}

header nav {
 float:right;
}
 header nav a{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s; 
}
.center{
text-align:center;
}
header nav a:hover {
color: #555; 
}
header.smaller #mainmenu a{
padding: 18px 20px 18px 20px !important;
color:#333;
}
header.smaller {
height: auto;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
border-bottom:solid 1px #ddd; 
}
header.smaller h1{
padding-top:5px;
}
.logo-smaller h1#logo {
width: 150px;
height:60px;
line-height: 65px;
font-size: 30px;
}
.logo-smaller h1#logo img{
width:auto;
height:60px;
line-height: 75px;
font-size: 30px;
}
.logo-smaller  h1#logo .logo-1{
display:none;
}
.logo-smaller  h1#logo .logo-2{
display:inline-block;
}
header.fixed #mainmenu a{
padding: 18px 20px 18px 20px !important;
color:#333;

}
header.fixed {
height: 70px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
border-bottom:solid 1px #ddd; 
}
header.fixed h1#logo {
width: 150px;
height:30px;
line-height: 65px;
font-size: 30px;
}
header.fixed h1#logo img{
width:auto;
height:30px;
line-height: 75px;
font-size: 30px;
}
header.fixed h1#logo img.logo-1{
display:none;
}
header.fixed h1#logo img.logo-2{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Um, where's the HTML?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the HTML, or a link.

Comment: float the meniu and the logo left

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML please!!